# changing parents parent class when changing select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ideally use a toggle instead of a condition but was not sure how as new to jQuery but think im getting the right logic.. or starting to with what i want to do.

By default the parent parent is grey which is for "updated" and "new" being green so want to toggle the class depending on whats set and when select in changed?

```js
$('.column.small select').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('grey')) {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('grey');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('green');
  }
});
```

```css
.column.small {
  color: white;
}
.grey {
  background: grey
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_1_Status" name="PC_Row_1_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_2_Status" name="PC_Row_2_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small green">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_3_Status" name="PC_Row_3_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u">Updated</option>
      <option value="n" selected="selected">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A quick suggestion.. If any of the answers below helped you then you need upvote and mark it has answer, probably the earliest and efficient one.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do it that way. Try with `parents` -

```
$('.column.small select').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).parents('.column').hasClass('grey')) {
    $(this).parents('.column').removeClass('grey');
    $(this).parents('.column').addClass('green');
  }
});
```

You can also use `closest` method for this. And you should use method chaining.

```
$(this).closest('.column').removeClass('grey').addClass('green');
```

And if you are using same object multiple time them try to avoid DOM element look ups multiple times to reduce the execution process. You can do this -

```
var parent_div= $(this).parents('.column');
if (parent_div.hasClass('grey')) {
   parent_div.removeClass('grey');
   parent_div.addClass('green');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptkhd004/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.closest` and make it in single line with `removeClass` and `addClass`

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).closest('.column').hasClass('grey')) {
    $(this).closest('.column').removeClass('grey').addClass('green');
  }
});
```

```css
.column.small {
  color: white;
}
.grey {
  background: grey
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_1_Status" name="PC_Row_1_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_2_Status" name="PC_Row_2_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small green">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_3_Status" name="PC_Row_3_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u">Updated</option>
      <option value="n" selected="selected">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or event with `.toggleClass` for both the class to get **activated/de-activated**

```
$(this).closest('.column').toggleClass('grey green');
```

Comment: when you change last dropdown value it is not working

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha It is not changing because OP hasn't provided any info  on whether he wants to `toggle` it back on `change` of `option` to `updated`

Comment: yes i know. but it functionally wrong. because it must toggle when option is changed

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha if that is the case he can just use `$(this).closest('.column').toggleClass('grey green');` line without any condition of checking `hasClass`. well functionally OP even hasn't specified that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('.column.small select').change(function() {
  $(this).parents('.column').toggleClass('grey green');
});
```

```css
.column.small {
  color: white;
}
.grey {
  background: grey
}
.green {
  background: green ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_1_Status" name="PC_Row_1_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_2_Status" name="PC_Row_2_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small green">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_3_Status" name="PC_Row_3_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u">Updated</option>
      <option value="n" selected="selected">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.column.small select').on('change', function() {
  var column = $(this).closest('.column');
  column.removeClass('green');
  if ($(this).find(':selected').text() == "New") {

    column.addClass('green');
  }

});
```

Comment: some comments or explanation would be nice

Comment: if the select has the text "New" add the green background else remove it

Answer (score 0):

I've completely changed the logic so that it runs on load as well as it's now much more dynamic, see a working jsFiddle here:
I've created it into a function, so it's called on load and also on change which is much better.

https://jsfiddle.net/wigster/6Lps0drd/2/

Also had to add an id to each option/select:

```
<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_1_Status" name="PC_Row_1_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option id="u" value="u">Updated</option>
      <option id="n" value="n" selected="selected">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small grey">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_2_Status" name="PC_Row_2_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option id="u" value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option id="n" value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column small green">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_3_Status" name="PC_Row_3_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option id="u" value="u">Updated</option>
      <option id="n" value="n" selected="selected">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function selectBoxColourUpdate(optionSelected) {
  var selectedId = $('option:selected', optionSelected).attr('id');
  console.log(selectedId);
  if (selectedId == "u") {
    optionSelected.parent().parent().removeClass('grey');
    optionSelected.parent().parent().addClass('green');
  } else {
    optionSelected.parent().parent().removeClass('green');
    optionSelected.parent().parent().addClass('grey');
  }
}
$('.column.small select').on('change', function() {
  selectBoxColourUpdate($(this));
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.column.small select').each(function (){
    selectBoxColourUpdate($(this));
  })
});
```